# make container div height and background colour expand with the content

Tags: html, css

First of all, I have looked into all the options, you pro's will say that I have not but I have :)
I just can't figure it out. The white background does not expand with the child div's.

this is the css

```
    #container{
        position: relative;
        background-color: #FFF;
        width: 900px;
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        border: 2px solid #FFF;

        }
#banner {
    height: 60px;
    width: 900px;
    background-color: #CFF;
    color: #F00;
    }
#menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 59px;
    height: 150px;
    left: -2px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    color:      #250517;
    background-color:   #6D6968;
    }
#menulogin{
    position: absolute;
    top: 209px;
    height: 100px;
    left: -2px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    color:      #250517;
    background-color:   #6D6968;
    }
table {
    border: none;
    }
#content {
        position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    left: 105px;
    width: 789px;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    }
```

These are the divs:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="banner"> Dit is de <strong>BETA</strong> van roekoerace.be! </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <table width="100" border="" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td><a href="../login.php">Login</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="../index.php">Profiel</a></td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="../duifkes.php">Duiven</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Wedstrijden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Training</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Markt</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
  <div id="menulogin"><!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="LoginMenu" --><!-- TemplateEndEditable --></div>
    <div id="content"><!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Inhoud" --><p>&nbsp;</p><!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
    </div> 
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: TABLE is the wrong tool for this job. Use a styled unordered list <UL>.

Comment: Why is everything absolutely positioned?

Comment: Euhm I don't know, I'm not good at the CSS-P...
Does the fact that I use a TABLE makes the problem or do you just say that as a hint?

Comment: You can't set a height on an element then expect it not to be observed! Take a look at you css for #menulogin. See the height: 100px in there? Comment /* it out */ or delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might help with what you're trying to do... take a look at it, and update your question if your issue is still included.

http://jsfiddle.net/rj5by/